# How can I insert the quantity in this shopping cart php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have successfully added items to the shopping cart. However, I am unable to add the quantity of it. I know that the problem is somewhere in addtocart where I am unable to pass the value from the index to the next page. I am still a beginner to this, so I have no idea how to fix this matter. I have tried using session but it still doesn't work

This is my code in index.php:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Innisnotfree</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            session_start();
           
            include'header.php';
            include'nav.php';
            include "connection.php";
            
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
            $res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        ?>
        
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="row">
               
                <?php while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ ?>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="<?php echo $r['image'];?>" alt="<?php echo $r['title']?>">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="addtocart.php?id=<?php echo $r['id']?>">
                                <h3><?php echo $r['title']?></h3>
                                <p> <?php echo $r['description']?></p>
                                <p><?php echo $r['price']?></p>
                                <p><input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control"/></p>
                                <p><input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" id="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart"/></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <?php include('footer.php')?>
 
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my addtocart.php

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) & !empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
 $items = $_SESSION['cart'];
 $cartitems = explode(",", $items);
 $items .= "," . $_GET['id'];
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];}
 header('location: index.php?status=success');
}else{
 $items = $_GET['id'];
 $_SESSION['cart'] = $items;
         if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        $_POST["quantity"] = $quantity ;}
 header('location: index.php?status=success');
          
}
 ?>
```

This is my cart.php:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            session_start();
            require_once('connection.php');
            include('header.php');
            include('nav.php');
            
            $items = $_SESSION['cart'];
            if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
                $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
            }
            $cartitems = explode(",", $items);
            
       
        ?>
        
         
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.NO</th>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price </th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        $total = 0;
                        $i =1;
                        
                        foreach ($cartitems as $key=>$id){
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
                            $res=  mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                            if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
                                $r = 0;
                                
                            }
                            else{
                                 $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
      
                            }
                        ?>
                   
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                        <td><a href="delcart.php?remove=<?php echo $key; ?>">Remove</a><?php echo $r['title'];?></td>
                        <td><?php  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){echo $_POST["quantity"];};?></td>
                        <td>$<?php echo $r['price'];?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    
                        $total = $total +  $r['price'];
                        $i++;
                        }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Total Price</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>$<?php echo $total; ?></strong></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Checkout</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
            include 'footer.php';
        ?>
        
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `session_start()` should be at top of your code before any output, this is why your session is not storing.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone In addtocart.php page, its at the top where she is having issue to add the product in cart. But you are right, session_start must always be at the top of the page.

Comment: @AmitGupta no it will get lost once it hits the other pages.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ohh ok fine.

Comment: Maybe this is your error or I'm just missing something: You are checking for `$_POST["quantity"]` data sent to cart.php, but when are you actually sending this data to cart.php? Because addtocart.php just grabs the variables, does nothing with them, then sends the user back to index.php.

Comment: $_POST["quantity"] didn't insert to your session cart

Answer (score 0):

see my shooping cart class and you can modify it as you want

```
class cart {
/**
 * add product to cart by id and quantity
 * @param type $pid product id
 * @param type $quantity 
 */
function add($pid,$quantity){

/*if cart dosen't exist initialize it and add the first product*/
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['quantity']=$quantity;
        echo 'Product successfully added';
    }
/*else if cart exist check if product exist to change quantity else add new product*/
    else {
/*if exist change quantity*/
        if($this->isexist($pid,$quantity)){
            echo 'Quantity updated successfully';
        }
/*else add new product in cart*/
        else{
            $m=$_SESSION['cart'];
            $max=count($m);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['productid']=$pid;
            $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['quantity']=$quantity;
            echo 'Product successfully added';
        }
    }

}

/**
 * check if product alredy exist in cart or not
 * @param type $pid product id
 * @param type $quantity
 * @return boolean if true the product is exist and the quantity change successfully
 */
function isexist($pid,$quantity) {
    $m=$_SESSION['cart'];
    $max=count($m);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        if($pid==$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid']){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['quantity']=$quantity;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

/**
 * delete product by product id
 * @param type $pid product id
 */
function delete($pid){
    $m=$_SESSION['cart'];
    $max=count($m);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        if($pid==$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid']){
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$i]);
        $_SESSION['cart']=array_values($_SESSION['cart']);$_SESSION['cart'.'num']-=1;break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * change quantity of exist product
 * @param type $pid product id
 * @param type $quantity
 */
function modify($pid,$quantity){
    $m=$_SESSION['cart'];
    $max=count($m);

    if($quantity>0){
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            if($pid==$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid']){
                $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['quantity']=$quantity;break;
            }
        }
    }

    else {$this->delete($pid);}

}

/**
 * show all items in your cart
 */
function show_cart() {

    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        echo 'id=>'.$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'].
             'quantity=>'.$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['quantity'].'<br>';
    }
}

}
```